# Meteor JS Can connect to compose.io on everything except iOS device?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, compose-db

I have been working on an application and using compose.io as my database platform. I am able connect to compose in web browser and iOS simulator with:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@aws-us-east-1-portal.6.dblayer.com:11111/dbName" meteor (run , run ios)
```

However when I try the same process with run ios-device --mobile-server, or ios-device --mobile-server -p 127.0.0.1:3000 it just keeps creating a local database instance. In Meteor documentation it says may need developer account, but I am assuming that was outdated as of Xcode 7 testing on your own device was free, unless this does not count for database connections.

Any ideas, is my command line string incorrect, or is a developer account required? Maybe something else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by disabling my cellular network, so that my mobile device(iPhone) and local machine(Mac) were using the same network(Wifi) guaranteed. Be to delete any exiting instance your Meteor app your device before running the following while the device and local machine are on the same network.

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@aws-us-east-1-portal.6.dblayer.com:11391/dbName" meteor run ios-device
```